# problem with not displaying content on selected pages

Tags: conditional-tags

My objective - Display some code on every page apart from 2 pages.

Now this code works fine with only one page (if its not `is_home`, display code)...

```
<?php if (!is_home()) { ?>  
(some content)
<?php ?>
```

... but when I try to do it for two pages, the rule fails, and the code is displayed on both the pages where I do not want it visible...

```
<?php if( !is_home() or !is_archive()) { ?> 
(some content)
<?php ?>
```

I am unsure why this fails, any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use **if ((!is_home()) || (!is_archive()))**

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing against two falses you have to use the logical AND operator, because BOTH have the be false.

```
<?php if( !is_home() && !is_archive()) { ?> 
(some content)
<?php ?>
```

Comment: Yes! I knew it was something like that but couldn't put my finger on it. Thanks!